# Debugging vb6 form inside Excel

Tags: excel, dll, com, vb6

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536157/debugging-vb6-form-inside-3rd-party-application#answer-17539171) describes how to debug a VB6 dll from inside another application. It is what I have done for years, but now it stopped working.

Here is my configuration:

1. Start a CAD application
2. The CAD loads a dll created in VB6
3. An Excel macro connects to the CAD using GetObject(, "MyCad.Application")
4. The macro asks the CAD to perform some tasks that use the VB6 dll
5. The macro loads the VB6 dll and uses it directly, without the CAD as a middle man

This configuration has always worked, both with Visual Studio running the dll in debug mode (where both the CAD and Excel would connect to the temporary instance created by Visual Studio) and with the compiled and registered version.

Recently part of this setup stopped working: with the compiled dll all the 5 steps listed above still work, in debugging mode only the first 4 steps work, but the 5th doesn't.

Why is the CAD application able to connect to both the compiled dll and the debugging version, but Excel only connects to the compiled one?

**EDIT**

When I debug the following snippet from Excel I get the exact same behavior, either with the declaration as `Object` or as `MyPlugin.Application`: I press F8 on the VBA IDE, the control passes to the VB6 IDE on the first line of the `Class_Initialize` function, I keep pressing F8 on VB6, and when the control returns to Excel I get `Run-time error'430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface'.

```
Dim A As Object
Set A = New MyPlugin.Application

Dim A As MyPlugin.Application
Set A = New MyPlugin.Application
```

**EDIT 2**

I found an horrible workaround: I sprinkle the VBA code with ugly conditional compilation statements like this and now I can debug, but it's really painful:

```
#If LATE_BINDING Then
  Function F() As Object
#Else
  Function F() As MyPlugin.MyClass
#End If
```

I can set `LATE_BINDING = 1` from the VBA project properties, so I can step from VBA code into VB6 code and debug without problems, or I can set `LATE_BINDING = 0` when I work on the VBA project without VB6 debugger open and take advantage of early binding.

Comment: When it doesn't work, how does it fail? Are you getting an error message for instance? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Sorry, I forgot, I edited the post and added some details about the error.

Comment: Can you check whether there were any updates to the CAD application, Excel, or Windows at the time it broke? Were you able to apply the procedure on more than one computer, and now it's broken on all of them, or is there only one computer involved?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. The last CAD update was in 2009, the last time I successfully ran a VBA+VB6+CAD debugging session was more than one year ago on an computer that I don't have anymore. I will try to create a new installation on another computer (now I have Win 10, I will try Win 7 too)